# Python HTTP Server Javascript function return value can't be displayed in .html

Tags: javascript, python, html, server

I have a server using Python that displays a HTML website at `localhost:8080`. The use of my javascript file is to connect to a SPS and to retrieve some data.

When I try the buttons on my website, the log shows the correct information in the browser console. However, I am unable to display the same value I display in the log on the HTML website itself.

server.py:

```
import http.server
import socketserver

# Set the port number you want to use
port = 8080

# Create a custom request handler to serve files
handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

# Create a TCP server
with socketserver.TCPServer(("", port), handler) as httpd:
    print(f"Serving on port {port}")

    # Start the server
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Your API Website</title>
</head>
<body> 
    <h1>Your API Website</h1>

    <script src="app.js" defer></script>

    <!-- Buttons for API methods -->
    <button id="loginBtn">Login</button>
    <button id="getPermissionsBtn">Get Permissions</button>
    <button id="pingBtn">Ping</button>
    <button id="readBtn">Read</button>

    <!-- Button to display all API implementations -->
    <button id="displayAllBtn">Display All</button>

    <!-- Result display area -->
    <div id="resultDisplay"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  function API() {
      this.token = null;
      this.requests = [];
  }

  API.prototype.login = function () {
      const payload = {
          id: 0,
          jsonrpc: '2.0',
          method: 'Api.Login',
          params: {
              user: '5AHIT',
              password: '5ahiT',
          },
      };

      const headers = {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Content-Length': JSON.stringify(payload).length,
          Host: '192.168.10.1',
      };

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open('POST', 'https://192.168.10.61/api/jsonrpc', true);
          Object.entries(headers).forEach(([key, value]) => xhr.setRequestHeader(key, value));

          xhr.onload = function () {
              const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
              console.log(response);

              if (response.result && response.result.token) {
                  this.token = response.result.token;
                  this.requests.push(response);
                  console.log('Token:', this.token);
                  displayResponse(response);
                  resolve();
              } else {
                  reject(new Error('Login failed.'));
              }
          }.bind(this);

          xhr.onerror = function () {
              reject(new Error('Network error during login.'));
          };

          xhr.send(JSON.stringify(payload));
      });
  };

  API.prototype.getPermissions = function () {
      const payload = {
          id: 1,
          jsonrpc: '2.0',
          method: 'Api.GetPermissions',
      };

      const headers = {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'X-Auth-Token': this.token,
      };

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open('POST', 'https://192.168.10.61/api/jsonrpc', true);
          Object.entries(headers).forEach(([key, value]) => xhr.setRequestHeader(key, value));

          xhr.onload = function () {
              const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
              console.log(response);

              if (response.result) {
                  for (const permission of response.result) {
                      console.log(permission);
                  }
                  this.requests.push(response);
                  resolve();
              } else {
                  reject(new Error('GetPermissions failed.'));
              }
          }.bind(this);

          xhr.onerror = function () {
              reject(new Error('Network error during GetPermissions.'));
          };

          xhr.send(JSON.stringify(payload));
      });
  };

  API.prototype.ping = function () {
      const payload = {
          id: 1,
          jsonrpc: '2.0',
          method: 'Api.Ping',
      };

      const headers = {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'X-Auth-Token': this.token,
      };

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open('POST', 'https://192.168.10.61/api/jsonrpc', true);
          Object.entries(headers).forEach(([key, value]) => xhr.setRequestHeader(key, value));

          xhr.onload = function () {
              const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
              console.log(response);
              this.requests.push(response);
              resolve();
          }.bind(this);

          xhr.onerror = function () {
              reject(new Error('Network error during Ping.'));
          };

          xhr.send(JSON.stringify(payload));
      });
  };

  API.prototype.read = function () {
      const payload = {
          id: 1,
          jsonrpc: '2.0',
          method: 'PlcProgram.Read',
          params: {
              var: '"dVisu".sinus',
          },
      };

      const headers = {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'X-Auth-Token': this.token,
      };

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open('POST', 'https://192.168.10.61/api/jsonrpc', true);
          Object.entries(headers).forEach(([key, value]) => xhr.setRequestHeader(key, value));

          xhr.onload = function () {
              const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
              console.log(response);
              this.requests.push(response);
              resolve();
          }.bind(this);

          xhr.onerror = function () {
              reject(new Error('Network error during Read.'));
          };

          xhr.send(JSON.stringify(payload));
      });
  };

  API.prototype.displayRequests = function () {
      console.log(this.requests);
  };

  function displayResponse(response) {
      const resultDisplay = document.getElementById('resultDisplay');
      resultDisplay.innerHTML = `<pre>${JSON.stringify(response, null, 2)}</pre>`;
  }

  const api = new API();

  function handleLogin() {
      api.login().then(api.displayRequests).catch(error => console.error(error.message));
  }

  function handleGetPermissions() {
      api.getPermissions().then(api.displayRequests).catch(error => console.error(error.message));
  }

  function handlePing() {
      api.ping().then(api.displayRequests).catch(error => console.error(error.message));
  }

  function handleRead() {
      api.read().then(api.displayRequests).catch(error => console.error(error.message));
  }

  function handleDisplayAll() {
      console.log('All API Implementations:');
      console.log('------------------------');
      console.log('1. Login');
      console.log('2. Get Permissions');
      console.log('3. Ping');
      console.log('4. Read');
  }

  document.getElementById('loginBtn').addEventListener('click', handleLogin);
  document.getElementById('getPermissionsBtn').addEventListener('click', handleGetPermissions);
  document.getElementById('pingBtn').addEventListener('click', handlePing);
  document.getElementById('readBtn').addEventListener('click', handleRead);
  document.getElementById('displayAllBtn').addEventListener('click', handleDisplayAll);

  window.onload = function () {
      api.login().then(api.displayRequests).catch(error => console.error(error.message));
  };
});
```

Anyone knows why I get this behaviour?